# Javascript bind function call to id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function that is called through an onclick event in an img. Inside that function I want to bind the same function to a separate div. No jQuery.

```
<img id="img1" onclick="toggle(this)" src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.Mde7815d5c3b846360c29e9aa3ea9a10fH0%26pid%3D15.1&f=1" alt="Image" style="width:128px; height:auto; cursor:pointer; z-index:0;"/>
  <p>
    Test text
  </p>
  <p>
    Test text 2
  </p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(doc){
      var mask = document.getElementById('overlay');
      var io = doc.tog ^= 1;
      doc.width_org = io ? doc.style.width : doc.width_org;
      mask.style.visibility = io ? "visible" : "hidden";
      doc.style.zIndex = io ? 2 : 0;
      doc.style.width = io ? (doc.naturalWidth + "px") : doc.width_org;
      doc.style.align = io ? "center" : "left";
      doc.style.vAlign = io ? "middle" : "top";
      doc.style.position = io ? "fixed" : "relative";
      doc.style.top = io ? "50%" : "0px";
      doc.style.left = io ? "50%" : "0px";
      doc.style.marginTop = io ? "-" + (doc.naturalHeight / 2) + "px" : "0px";
      doc.style.marginLeft = io ? "-" + (doc.naturalWidth / 2) + "px" : "0px";
    }
  </script>
  <div id="overlay" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; background:#000000; opacity:0.8; z-index:1; visibility:hidden"></div>
```

I want to bind a callback to toggle for the id `overlay` that passes doc back through, effectively, clicking the img will toggle its gallery effect, and make it so clicking the div overlay closes it as well as clicking the img.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a single line at the end of `toggle` (to call toggle for the currently opened image onclick of div, and then clear the onclick event) like this

```
document.getElementById('overlay').onclick = function () { 
    toggle(doc); 
    this.onclick = null; 
};
```

Here's a code snippet for that, click run

```html
<img id="img1" onclick="toggle(this)" src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.Mde7815d5c3b846360c29e9aa3ea9a10fH0%26pid%3D15.1&f=1" alt="Image" style="width:128px; height:auto; cursor:pointer; z-index:0;"/>
  <p>
    Test text
  </p>
  <p>
    Test text 2
  </p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(doc){
      var mask = document.getElementById('overlay');
      var io = doc.tog ^= 1;
      doc.width_org = io ? doc.style.width : doc.width_org;
      mask.style.visibility = io ? "visible" : "hidden";
      doc.style.zIndex = io ? 2 : 0;
      doc.style.width = io ? (doc.naturalWidth + "px") : doc.width_org;
      doc.style.align = io ? "center" : "left";
      doc.style.vAlign = io ? "middle" : "top";
      doc.style.position = io ? "fixed" : "relative";
      doc.style.top = io ? "50%" : "0px";
      doc.style.left = io ? "50%" : "0px";
      doc.style.marginTop = io ? "-" + (doc.naturalHeight / 2) + "px" : "0px";
      doc.style.marginLeft = io ? "-" + (doc.naturalWidth / 2) + "px" : "0px";
      document.getElementById('overlay').onclick = function () { toggle(doc); this.onclick = null; };
    }
  </script>
  <div id="overlay" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; background:#000000; opacity:0.8; z-index:1; visibility:hidden"></div>
```